# SignalR (.Net) Database to Grid (Knockout)

Tags: signalr

I am relatively new to SignalR and every tutorial seems to be for a chat application or some variant. This is good to get to grips, but I am looking to have a grid that updates automatically on a database change. I have even gone through Pluralsights tutorial which shows this as a sample but then all it's practicals are for a chat application.

I do understand that this is what a search engine is for, but I have exhausted this channel, as above I found plenty of tutorials but all seem to be for a chat application.

Has anyone else noticed this, and if so has anyone found any good resources for tutorials that deal with real-time grids. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SqlDependency but it tend to be heavily dependent to SQL (Thus the name). I think its bad practice to have a solution dependent to the database, sooner or later you also want updates from the Domain only etc.

I have made a EventAggregator proxy for signalR that can pick up events decoupled from domain and database. Check it out here

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Install with nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

It has both a .NET and javascript client, check the wiki for how to set it up, and here is a demo

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Comment: Thanks Anders, I will give it a go. It makes sense what your saying.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that most of the tutorials demonstrate a chat application, since that's the easiest way to show off the technology. Once you start demonstrating a more complex sample, there are design patterns that don't really have to do with the technology.

Here's a tutorial that demonstrates how to update the client based on changes from a server:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20

Here's a demo that uses SqlDependency to update the client:

http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

(The above is SignalR 1.0, so see the Updating document for info on how to change it to 2.0):

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20

Comment: Thanks for the reply, those links will be very helpful to me.